# divergence theorem: what means continuously differentiable in the presence of countably finite discrete charges

Tags: lebesgue-measure, differential-topology, divergence-theorem

**Context**

This question is similar, but not identicle, to [3]. Though in [3], it appears the central question revolves around a piece-wise transition between two regions of the real number line.

From [1],

> ``Suppose $V$  is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is  compact  and has a  piece-wise smooth surface $S$. If $\mathbf{F}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field defined on a  neighborhood of $V$, then
> $$\iiint_V\left(\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{F}\right)\,dV=  \oint_S   (\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}})\,dS .''$$

Let's say, for example, that $\mathbf{F}$ is due to a finite countable number of  discrete electric charges located inside of $V$. Let's further say that the position of the $i^\text{th}$ electric charge is $\mathbf{r}_i$. Since the electric field is an inverse square-law, the electric field is undefined at positions $\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_3,\ldots$.  Similarly the derivative does not exist at those positions. Yet, the divergence theorem holds.

**Questions**

(1) Am I misunderstanding what is meant by ``neighbourhood of a set?'' [2]

(2) Am I erroneous in my understanding that the electric field is not continuously differentiable at the positions $\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_3,\ldots$?

(3) Is the predicate ``If $\mathbf{F}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field'' either too restrictive, or inadequately specified? Maybe it should read: If $\mathbf{F}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field at all locations in $V$ up to a countable finite collection of points of measure 0.?

(4) Would a more suitable predicate by, if $\mathbf{F}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field in a neighborhood of $S$?

(5) Bottom line: what am I not understanding here?

**Citations**

[1] Wikipedia contributors. Divergence theorem [Internet]. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia; 2020 Dec 22, 08:32 UTC [cited 2021 Feb 19]. Available from: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Divergence_theorem&oldid=995678588.

[2] Wikipedia contributors. Neighbourhood (mathematics) [Internet]. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia; 2021 Feb 12, 00:18 UTC [cited 2021 Feb 19]. Available from: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Neighbourhood_(mathematics)&oldid=1006271578.

[3] [Divergence theorem non continuously differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687600/divergence-theorem-non-continuously-differentiable)

Comment: If the point charges are in the region $V$, then $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$ is not everywhere defined, except in the sense of distribution theory. That the distributional divergence theorem *also* holds is not immediate from the proof of the classical one.

Comment: No, the statement is true. It doesn't encompass all situations in which the divergence theorem conclusion holds, but it's true anyway.

Comment: When you start to generalise this to distributional derivative $\operatorname{div}F$ and nonsmooth surface $S$ etc., you have many choices which way to go.  For example, you can fix the surface $\sigma$ to be sufficiently smooth and vary $F$, or the other way, or you try to do something in-between with geometric measure theory.  Let's start with Bent Fuglede's PhD thesis.